# CodeHS fails my program even though it fully works

Tags: python

So I'm learning coding on python right now with CodeHS, and one of my assignments is to make a word ladder (each word has a one letter difference) and the automatic grader say I'm failing every test despite meeting all expectations.  After listing what was expected and what I did, it finds that the difference is "something wrong with the code."  In my code, there is no other way to get an error other than to input a string when it asks for an index.  Could someone point out any possible way I that an error could occur? Here's my code:

```
def get_index():
    while True:
        index = int(input("Enter an index (-1 to quit): "))
        if index < -1 or index >= len(word):
            print("Invalid index")
            continue
        elif index == -1:
            exit()
        return index
def get_letter():
    while True:
        letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if len(letter) != 1:
            print("Must be exactly one character!")
            continue
        if letter != letter.lower():
            print("Character must be a lowercase letter!")
            continue
        return letter
word = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
while True:
    indLet = [get_index(),get_letter()]
    word = list(word)
    word[indLet[0]] = indLet[1]
    print("".join(word))
```

Comment: Why do you use a list `indLet`? Use `index = get_index()` and `letter = get_letter()`

Comment: Do you need to check that it's actually a letter? Or that `word` is just a single word?

Comment: Can you post the detailed requirements?

Comment: @Barmar 
I actually tried the index and letter variables, which works the same, but my unit is on lists and tuples, so I'm seeing if I need to use one.  Allow me to also post the requirements:
You should have a function, get_index, that repeatedly asks the user for an index until they enter a valid integer that is within the acceptable range of indices for the initial string. You should have another function, get_letter, that repeatedly asks the user for a letter until they enter exactly one lowercase letter. 
Then print the result, with the specified letter replacing the specified index.

Comment: Put the details in the question. I think the list of letters is the one that satisfies what you're studying in the unit.

Comment: Your script seems to work as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, I and my teacher have verified this script works, it could just be the website acting up.  I was just curious what was going on.  In any case, my teacher has marked my assignment as correct, so I guess this question is as good as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been resolved, but to anyone in the future, the reason why you're getting "Something wrong with the code." even though your program works is because you're using exit() or sys.exit() or raise SystemExit(0) or something else like that. For some reason, CodeHS doesn't like this and you'll need to find another way to end your program. For example, I did mine like this:

```
def get_index(word):
    while True:
        index = int(input("Enter an index (-1 to quit): "))
        if (index >= len(word)):
            print("Invalid index")
        elif (index < -1):
            print("Invalid index")
        else:
            return index

def get_letter():
    while True:
        letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if (len(letter) > 1):
            print("Must be exactly one character!")
        elif (letter.lower() != letter):
            print("Character must be a lowercase letter!")
        else:
            break
    return letter

initialWord = input("Enter a word: ")
currentwordList = list(initialWord)
while True:
    currentIndex = get_index(initialWord)
    if (currentIndex == -1):
        break
    currentLetter = get_letter()
    currentwordList[currentIndex] = currentLetter
    print("".join(currentwordList))
```

Answer (score -1):

yo mate! I am too lazy to explain but here is the code:

```
def get_index(word):
    while True:
        try:
            index = int(input("Enter an index: "))
            if index == -1:
                return index
            elif index >= len(word):
                print ("invalid index")
            elif index <= -1:
                print ("invalid index")
            else:
                return index
        except ValueError:
            print ("invalid index")
            
def get_letter():
    
    while True:
        
        letter = str(input("Enter a letter: "))
    
        if letter.islower() and len(letter)==1:
            return letter
    
        elif  not letter.islower():  
            print ("Character must be a lowercase letter!")
  
        elif len(letter) > 1:
            print ("Must be exactly one character!")

def word_ladder(word):
    
    while True:
        index = get_index(word)
        if index == -1:
            return
        else:
            letter=get_letter() 
            
            word = list(word)
            word[index] = letter
            word = ("").join(word)
            print (word)

word = input("Enter a word: ") 

word_ladder(word)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).